# Rubyにおける複素数expの計算でRange Errorがでてしまいます

Tags: ruby

Rubyに関する以下のコードでRange Errorが出てしまうのですが，どのように対処したら良いでしょうか

初歩的な質問ですが宜しくお願いします．

```
require 'complex'

rnd = Random.new(1234)

# 複素数で表示させたい
p (1.0 / 17.7827) * Math.exp(Complex(Math.cos(rnd.rand(1.0)), Math.sin(rnd.rand(1.0))) * 2 * Math::PI)
```

以下，エラーコードです

```
prog.rb:5:in `to_f': can't convert 6.168304426149614+3.661527184496933i into Float (RangeError)
from prog.rb:5:in `exp'
from prog.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `Math.exp()` は複素数に対応していませんので、[CMath.exp](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/CMath/m/exp.html) を使うと良さそうです。`require 'cmath'` として、`p (1.0 / 17.7827) * CMath.exp(Complex(...`

Comment: `require 'cmath'` にあったのですね．試したらできました．ありがとうございます．

Comment: @metropolis よろしければ、コメントの内容を回答へ転記いただけますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.exp()` は複素数に対応していませんので、[CMath.exp](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/CMath/m/exp.html) を使うと良さそうです。

```
require 'cmath'
p (1.0 / 17.7827) * CMath.exp(Complex(...
```

([metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis)さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/49892/ruby%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E8%A4%87%E7%B4%A0%E6%95%B0exp%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%88%E7%AE%97%E3%81%A7range-error%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99#comment52021_49892)より)